# libgdx Game got black screen and closed(without any message) after some time being played

Tags: java, android, memory-management, libgdx

I'm trying to implement parallax background in my game..

CODE:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen{
private huntRun game;
private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
private Viewport gamePort;
private Hud hud;

private Texture bg;
float sourceX = 0;

private TmxMapLoader maploader;
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

public PlayScreen(huntRun game){
    this.game = game;
    //create cam used to follow character through cam world
    gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();

    bg = new Texture("bg_play.jpg");
    bg.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);

    //create a FitViewport to maintain virtual aspect ration despite screen size
    gamePort = new FitViewport(huntRun.V_WIDTH, huntRun.V_HEIGHT, gamecam);

    //create our game HUD for scores/timers/level info
    hud = new Hud(game.batch);

    maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = maploader.load("ground.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
    gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

public void handleInput(float dt){
    //if right button pressed
    if(hud.flag_R == true){
        gamecam.position.x += 200 * dt;
        sourceX += 100 * dt;
    }
    //if left button pressed
    if(hud.flag_L == true){
        gamecam.position.x -= 200 * dt;
        sourceX -= 100 * dt;
    }
}

public void update(float dt){
    handleInput(dt);
    gamecam.update();
    renderer.setView(gamecam);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);
    SpriteBatch sb = new SpriteBatch();

    float width = 4500;
    float height= 720;
    float uRight = width * 1 / bg.getWidth();
    float vTop= height * 1 / bg.getHeight();

    //Clear the game screen with black
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(bg, sourceX, 0, width, height, uRight, vTop, 0, 0);
    effect.draw(sb, delta);
    sb.end();
    renderer.render();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
    hud.stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gamePort.update(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    hud.generator.dispose();
    bg.dispose();
}
```

}

My libgdx game is running perfectly for somtimes on real devices. But after opening my game again after some time it shows black screen and get closed without any message. I have carefully disposed Spritebatch, stage, and all textures.

Any idea what can I do more? I have read many questions regarding it here and on Google and did whatever considerable solutions are available but no luck. I have also checked this Black Screen After Restart but no luck for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar error.
For me the problem was a memory leak error.

On your code the memory leak could happen beacause you inizialized the SpriteBatch on the render method.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);
    SpriteBatch sb = new SpriteBatch();  //<- here
    ...
```

Try to inizialize it on the show() method.